# Simulating keyboard presses using python in linux

Tags: python, xdotool

I tried simulating with xdotool but an exception is raised like

> Error: Can't open display: (null) even after trying with export DISPLAY=':0.0'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried?

Comment: I tried giving xdotool from command prompt #xdotool shift+~ . Even that was not working was for me

Comment: I believe you are using the wrong key command to type the ~ key, maybe use ` instead because that is the lower case, or maybe it has a different name, I can't currently test this so I'm unsure.

Comment: yeah you are correct i used shift+~ instead of shift+`

Comment: This is what I tried. Now it is giving me xdotool not found error #!/usr/bin/python
import os
cmd = 'xdotool shift+\`'
os.system(cmd)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so your real problem here is that you didn't even use `xdotool key <keys>` you just used `xdotool <keys>` but besides that if you want to send a backtick you need to use `xdotool key grave` and for the tilde use `xdotool key shift+grave`